# MFC: Line control for separating parts of dialog boxes in C++

Tags: c++

I am looking for the class name of an MFC Common Control for the caption and line that divide the dialog box into sections: "Section", "Headers and Footers", "Page, and "Preview" in the image below.

It appears that this likely a standard control, but I haven't been able to figure out how to create it so far.

[image]

Comment: When you post a question like this to StackOverflow you need to include the source code that shows how far you have gotten and what you already tried that doesn't work.  Then people can make intelligent responses.  It is called the MCVE rule or Minimal, Complete and Verifable Example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am not sure if there is a control for this. I was trying to use the LineTo(), !https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145029(v=vs.85).aspx. but it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're dead set on that exact look, this is done with a group box. It will look a little different, as it draws a box all the way around a group, so the result would look something like this:

[image]

If you're really set on a line at the top but not bottom or sides, you'll probably have to do that yourself. You'd (at least normally) do this with a custom control. As simple of one as you're looking at here (caption, line, doesn't need to accept any input from the user) that'll be a trivial one to implement, but you'd normally do it as a separate project, then use that in your project.

Comment: I don't want it to be a groupbox. I have a label and I need a line in front of it. And I am trying to this programmatically.

Comment: @Yamini: You *don't* want to try to draw directly into a dialog. That's a really lousy idea that almost never works out well. As such, you seem to have narrowed it down to developing a custom control. You could probably base it on a static control (which will handle the caption) so your control just draws a line from just past the caption to the right boundary of its client rectangle.